# Colon/Semicolon remapping with xmodmap with two active setxkbmap layouts

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb

Gentlemen,

I'm a non-native english speaker and need a second language layout. And I'm a heavy Vim user, and use `:` much more often than `;`. At the moment they are remapped in `.vimrc`, buth that causes confusion when I'm in console (and everywhere else), so I decided to remap them directly in `.xinitrc` (I know I can put it in `.Xmodmap`).

The following works fine:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:toggle # change layout with AltGr
xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = colon semicolon" # remap : and ;
```

except that that key only works in `us` layout. If I switch to `ru` it does absolutely nothing, not even [semi]colon (expected it to print 'ж' and 'Ж').

I know xmodmap is responsible for translation KEYCODE to a KEYSYM, and I'm messing that up, but I would at least expect it to print capital letter instead of lowercase and vice versa.

Is there something I'm doing completely wrong or am I just missing something?

PS Archlinux `Linux version 3.10.3-1-ARCH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, seems it needs to be passed as a third KEYSYM argument:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = colon semicolon Cyrillic_ZHE"
```